# Algorithm used for CRC calculation in PQDIF

Tags: c

What is the algorithm used for CRC calculation in PQDIF file?
I have tried different CRC calculator but am unable to calculate exact CRC/checksum for records.
If anyone can help ??

Answer (score 1):

ADLER-32 checksum is the algorithm used for calculating CRC in PQDIF files.
The code is available at wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is CRC-32 (based on documentation), you can use the following Stack Overflow thread to see how to calculate CRC-32 in `C`: [How is a CRC32 checksum calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587766/how-is-a-crc32-checksum-calculated)

Comment: Thank you. Got the CRC method used for PODIF CRC calculation. It is ADLER-32 checksum.

Comment: Great that you sorted it out, it would be great if you can answer your one question so that it will be kept on file for future searches