# how to make the result of crc32 match the cksum?

Tags: c, crc32

I have the code and have to change 0x3B9ACA02432543 to some value that will make the result of this code equal to cksum result.

I tried to change it to cksum default value that is 0x04C11DB7 but the result values were different

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        FILE *f = NULL;
        int c;

        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (f == NULL)
            perror("fopen()");
        else {
            int size = 0;
            int crc;
            int c;
            int i, j;
            int crc_table[256];
            for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                crc = i;
                for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x3B9ACA02432543 : crc >> 1;

                crc_table[i] = crc;
            }
            crc = 0;

            while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
                ++size;
                crc = crc_table[(crc ^ c) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);
            }
            crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
            printf("%u\n", crc);
        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: don't use `int`

Comment: This likely requires selecting the appropriate *unsigned* type, like `uint64_t`. It's far from clear why that constant is used, though. There are [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587766/how-is-a-crc32-checksum-calculated) which show how it could be done.

Comment: Where did you find this code where you say "I have the code"? And where in the world did the constant `0x3B9ACA02432543` come from? That is not the polynomial for any CRC that I've seen. It would be the polynomial for at least a 52-bit CRC, more likely a 64-bit CRC. Not a 32-bit CRC.

Comment: What system is your `cksum` on? What options are you using? There are many variants of `cksum` that compute different hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not say what operating system or source of `cksum` you are using. It is different on different systems. On my macOS (BSD-derived) system, `cksum -o 3` will compute the standard CRC-32 that you may be referring to.

In that case, you need set the initial CRC to `0xffffffff`, and you need to use the reflection of the polynomial, `0x04c11db7`, which is `0xedb88320`. Also you should use a type assured to be at least 32 bits in length. `long` is, `int` is not. You also need to use unsigned types for CRC calcuations, so that shifting down doesn't copy the high bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        FILE *f = NULL;
        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (f == NULL)
            perror("fopen()");
        else {
            unsigned long crc;
            int c;
            int i, j;
            unsigned long crc_table[256];
            for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                crc = i;
                for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;
                crc_table[i] = crc;
            }
            crc = 0xffffffff;
            while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
                crc = crc_table[(crc ^ c) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
            crc ^= 0xffffffff;
            printf("%lu\n", crc);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The [POSIX cksum](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cksum.html) is yet another variant. It uses the non-reflected CRC, starts with `0` instead of `0xffffffff`, and appends the length of the data to the data for the CRC computation. That length is in little-endian order with the least number of bytes needed to represent the length. For convenience, I used the explicitly-sized integers provided by C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        FILE *f = NULL;
        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (f == NULL)
            perror("fopen()");
        else {
            uint32_t crc;
            uint32_t crc_table[256];
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                crc = i << 24;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x04c11db7 : crc << 1;
                crc_table[i] = crc;
            }
            uint64_t size = 0;
            crc = 0;
            int c;
            while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
                size++;
                crc = crc_table[(crc >> 24) ^ c] ^ (crc << 8);
            }
            while (size) {
                crc = crc_table[(crc >> 24) ^ (size & 0xff)] ^ (crc << 8);
                size >>= 8;
            }
            crc = ~crc;
            printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)crc);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good reply.  But if the OP is using constants like "0x3B9ACA02432543" and making declarations like "int crc_table[256];" ... it probably wouldn't hurt to emphasize the distinctions between "signed" and "unsigned", the possible difference between "long", and "uint32_t" and "uint64_t", and possible issues with "Endianness".

Comment: @paulsm4 There is no endianess coming into play here. The CRC is being printed simply as an integer.

Comment: As you well know, endianess *CAN* come into play with CRC calculations and comparisons in general.  Even the [link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cksum.html): you cited mentions this: "If a file is transmitted between two systems and undergoes any data transformation (such as changing little-endian byte ordering to big-endian), identical CRC values cannot be expected. Implementations performing such transformations may extend cksum to handle such situations."  It's a potential consideration the OP should definitely be aware of.

Comment: Yet it does not come into play _in this question_.

Answer (score 3):

To make the code compatible with the `cksum` utility, you'll need to use the same algorithm that `cksum` uses. The `cksum` utility typically uses a CRC algorithm with a polynomial of `0x04C11DB7`. Here are some issues in your code that need to be addressed:

The polynomial `0x3B9ACA02432543` is too large for a 32-bit CRC. The polynomial should be a 32-bit value, usually `0x04C11DB7` for `cksum`.

You need to initialize `crc` to `0xFFFFFFFFUL` at the start of the calculation.

The table initialization and calculation algorithm seem to be incorrect for a typical CRC32 calculation.

This is what you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        FILE *f = NULL;
        int c;

        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (f == NULL)
            perror("fopen()");
        else {
            unsigned int crc;
            unsigned int crc_table[256];
            unsigned int poly = 0x04C11DB7;  // Polynomial for cksum
            unsigned int temp_crc;

            // Build CRC table
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                temp_crc = i << 24;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (temp_crc & 0x80000000)
                        temp_crc = (temp_crc << 1) ^ poly;
                    else
                        temp_crc <<= 1;
                }
                crc_table[i] = temp_crc;
            }

            crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;  // Initialize CRC

            while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
                crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc_table[((crc >> 24) ^ c) & 0xFF];
            }

            crc = ~crc;  // Finalize CRC
            printf("%u\n", crc);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code gives me 2392487686 but cksum gives 1403953672 what`s the problem?

Comment: ЯДPTГФИ, `unsigned int crc;` and friends better as `uint32_t crc;` as many applications using CRC exist on 16-bit `unsigned` platforms.

Comment: I am not aware of a `cksum` variant that computes this particular CRC-32. What system are you using?